# "alex" command for the Alex lexer doesn't work

Tags: command-line, package-management

I'm trying to write a lexer using the Alex lexer for Haskell. I [installed Alex](https://www.haskell.org/alex/) with

```
$ cabal install alex
```

which seems to have worked. Then I [try their example](https://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/introduction.html) with

```
$ alex Tokens.x
```

and I get

```
The program 'alex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install alex
```

Have I done something wrong? What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

My friend answered for me elsewhere. Turns out I had the wrong path.

I will include the troubleshooting he did just in case other people have a different problem than me:

alex installed in .cabal/bin. To make sure, try

```
cd ~/.cabal/bin
```

and

```
./alex
```

If that works, then edit the file /.bashrc by putting this line at the bottom

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin"
```